# Reading sudo password from a pipe

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, vi

I try to use vi commands in a script, in addition I try to pass sudo password in same script. So I have something like:

```
echo mypassword | bash -c "echo $'Goappendthis\E:x\n' | sudo vi /etc/test"
```

vi command is successful but it still keeps asking password. How I can do it w/o password so I can run same command for multiple hosts in a script?

Comment: BTW, invoking it as `ex` will put `vi` into a mode designed for noninteractive use, or using `vi -s scriptfile` will read vi commands to run from `scriptfile`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Weirdly, a company wise policy won't allow me to change root owned files with sed, awk, python or perl one liners. It looks like it just allows modifying files by using sudo vi, and given I have hundreds of hosts to modify, I need to find a way to automate this.

So basically I need to run sudo vi same file add a line at the end of file and then save it. How I can do it otherwise?

Comment: Even if you're complying with the policy's letter, you're certainly not complying with its spirit here. Anyhow, the typical Right Thing is to use facilities provided by whichever orchestration system -- Puppet, Chef, SaltStack, CFEngine, etc etc -- your company uses to templatize the file's generation.

Comment: ...can you kick this up the ladder a few times to find out who's responsible for the policy, and what they have in mind as approved practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Don't do this. Use a privilege escalation mechanism that doesn't require passwords to be passed around.

Second: Unless given `-S` or `--stdin`, `sudo` reads passwords directly from the TTY, not from stdin.

Third: You need to direct the password to `sudo`'s stdin *without* also overriding `vi`'s stdin. Doing that might look like the following:

```
echo mypassword | sudo --stdin -- bash -c "echo $'Goappendthis\E:x\n' | vi /etc/test"
```

Comment: I know this is not ideal solution but for the moment I can use as a workaround. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In many situation you wouldn't want to pipe the password, but to keep sudo **credentials refreshed**:

```
refreshPermissions () {
    local pid="${1}"

    while kill -0 "${pid}" 2> /dev/null; do
        sudo -v
        sleep 10
    done
}

refreshPermissions "$$" &
```

Then if a **command** needs root permissions within your program just do:

```
sudo [command]
```

And no password will be requested.